# filter out list elements that match another list and preserve the original list order

Tags: python, list

Lets say i have following list

```
periods = ['2017 Q1', 'TEST2', '2018 Q4','2017 Q2', '2019Q3', '2017 Q3', '2017 Q4', '2017 FY', 'TEST']
```

I want to filter on periods to return any elements in the list that contain elements from this list

```
master_list = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'S1', 'S2', 'FY']
```

So i would expect

```
filtered = ['2017 Q1', '2018 Q4','2017 Q2', '2019 Q3', '2017 Q3', '2017 Q4', '2017 FY']
```

When i do something like this

```
a = [period for period in periods for master in master_list if period in master]
```

But this returns:

```
filtered = ['2017 Q1', '2017 Q2', '2019 Q3', '2017 Q3', '2017 Q4' ,'2018 Q4' ,'2017 FY']
```

This one has been reordered.

Comment: Apart from the answers below, you can also check out the `any` operator. i.e. `filtered = [i for i in periods if any(x in i for x in master_list)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if `master in period`:

```
master_list = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'S1', 'S2', 'FY']
periods = ['2017 Q1', 'TEST2', '2018 Q4', '2017 Q2', '2019Q3', '2017 Q3', '2017 Q4', '2017 FY', 'TEST']
a = [period for period in periods for master in master_list if master in period]

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
['2017 Q1', '2018 Q4', '2017 Q2', '2019Q3', '2017 Q3', '2017 Q4', '2017 FY']
```

**Explanation**

The expression `'2017 Q1' in 'Q1'` checks if `'2017 Q1'` is a substring of `'Q1'` which is `False`, on the other hand `'Q1' in '2017 Q1`' is `True`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the resulting list is correct as your condition is (period in master) which would never be True.
Why not do something straightforward like:

```
filtered = []
for period in periods:
  for master in master_list:
    if master in period:
      filtered.append(period)
```